# Is reversal of magnetic polarity in a planet an instantaneous occurence?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization, earth

Just what the title states -

Does reversal of magnetic poles in a planet refer to the point in time when reversal is complete?

OR

Does it refer to the entire drawn out process (assuming the poles flip gradually from 0 through 180 degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the term "reversal of magnetic poles" doesn't have a strict definition, so I suppose different commentators might use it in different ways. However I suspect most of us would use it to describe the whole process.

You describe the process as "drawn out" but no-one knows how long it takes because the dynamics of the Earth's core are poorly understood. On a geological timescale the process looks instantaneous, but then geological timescales are pretty long. [Models](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2007/mar/09/molten-sodium-mimics-earths-magnetic-field-flipping) suggest it could be pretty quick, though how realistic the liquid sodium models are is open to debate.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia article [wikipedia article on Geomagnetic reversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_reversal) seems like a pretty good place to start. See the section titled "Duration".

"Most estimates for the duration of a polarity transition are between 1,000 and 10,000 years."... but some people argue (very controversially) that some reversals in the past have been as quick as a few months.